Concat cells to merge names but if blank ignore
I have three columns of data:




A
B
C




1
First Name
Surname
Preferred Name



I would like the value in Column E to show First Name, Surname and Preferred Name in Brackets if there is one and no brackets if there is no preferred name.
The formula I have so far is
=CONCAT(A1," ",B1," (",(C1),")")

Is there a way to stop C1 being picked up by the formula if it is blank?
Formula:
=CONCAT(A1," ",B1," (",(C1),")")


Try the following formula-
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A1,B1,IF(C1<>"","("&C1&")",""))


